# Appending text to file c#

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

How would I append the text to the file using the code below?
I notice there is an option to append in the FileStream fs declaration line; but this is not where I want to put it.

CODE:

```
        Console.WriteLine(s2 + "g");
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(s2 + ".txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
        Console.SetOut(sw);
        Console.WriteLine(s2);
        sw.Close();
```

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use `File.AppendAllText`? And what do you mean by "but this is not where I want to put it"?

Comment: Because I want to either open the file if it is there, or if one does not exist create it.

Comment: Holy Batman! What on earth are you trying to do? (You will be excused if you are a Java programmer)

Comment: And what makes you think that `File.AppendAllText` won't do that?

Comment: @user3744373: And did you read the docs?

Comment: Ill take a look at File.AppendAllText now.Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

From the MSDN documentation of [`File.AppendAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Opens a file, appends the specified string to the file, and then
>   closes the file. If the file does not exist, this method creates a
>   file, writes the specified string to the file, then closes the file.

Simply:

```
File.AppendAllText(@"YourPathHere", "My awesome appended string!");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `File.AppendAllText` for that:

```
File.AppendAllText(@"c:\path\file.txt", "text content");
```

You can set a `FileShare` to allow multiple access with this `File.Open` command like

```
File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
```

Comment: Having two different handles writing to the same file is a recipe for disaster unless you're very careful to flush after every write. `File.AppendAllText` does flush before closing the file, but a `Write` doesn't, by default.